# Regex_like - Passing comparison string as a query - Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have the following table :

```
SrNo   Name
------------
 1     TOM
 2     JOHN
 3     HENRY
```

Running the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE regexp_LIKE (NAME, '^(TO|HEN)')
```

gives the output:

```
SrNo   Name
------------
 1     TOM    
 3     HENRY
```

If I run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (NAME, SELECT '^(' || 'TO' || '|' || 'HE' || ')' FROM DUAL )
```

I get the error

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

How may I pass the query correctly for this REGEXP_LIKE to work ?

Thanks,
Monica

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to surround the subquery with brackets to make it work. The following query should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (NAME, (
  SELECT '^(' || 'TO' || '|' || 'HE' || ')' FROM DUAL
) );
```

A SQLFiddle is available here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/072da/3